# Python injecting newlines when using f.write for no reason

Tags: python

to the best of my knowledge this hasn't been asked before and I'm at a loss. I have a python script that takes a bunch of strings and writes them to file in csv format. However in my write function python seems to be adding newlines and I cannot figure out how. Here's my code

```
monday_break_one = "2:00 PM - 2:15 PM"
monday_break_two = "3:30 PM - 3:45 PM"
day_one_string = "3/27/2017"


mb1s,mb1e= monday_break_one.split(" - ")
mb2s,mb2e= monday_break_two.split(" - ")
foo = ','
f = open('outputcsv.txt','w')
f.write("Subject,Start Date,Start Time, End Date ,End Time, All day Event, Categories,Show Time As\n")
f.write("Break 1," )
f.write(day_one_string + foo + mb1s + foo + day_one_string + foo + mb1e)
```

My output looks like this

```
Subject,Start Date,Start Time, End Date ,End Time, All day Event,Categories,Show Time As

Break 1,3/27/2017
,2:00 PM,3/27/2017
,2:15 PM
```

and it just doesn't make sense to me because it seems like my output has a new line after each instance of my "day_one_string" but that string really only equals "3/27/2017" and I've checked it multiple times through printing it to console. I would be wildly grateful for any help or pointers here, I am pulling my hair out trying to figure out where the new line is coming from.

Comment: You sure there is an extra newline there? I can't reproduce this with your code. Also, just use the csv module for this stuff.

Comment: Adding `f.close()` at the end is good practice...

Comment: Better practice is to use `with open` so you don't have to remember to close anything..

Comment: I feel like I"m going crazy. I wish I could screenshare with you guys because my code for some reason is adding a new line with each one

Comment: is the encoding `utf-8`?

Comment: Well, you can post the raw file somewhere. As in, upload, not cut and paste. Also, what OS, python version, etc.

Comment: does [this](https://ideone.com/wpwyR4) code have the same issue?

Comment: Well my all of my source code can be found here not going to lie it's pretty sloppy so please don't judge me haha. it basically reads in a text file, determines the date of the week for the schedule and parses through to look for lunch and break times to the be written to a .csv I can import into outlook. https://pastebin.com/dttmPTN1   https://pastebin.com/HydDPKKF also if you want my input and output files they look like this https://pastebin.com/GXAwr7y7 and https://pastebin.com/AQ7f0DXP

Comment: Ok but you're not running the actual code you put in your question and reproducing the same behaviour, then, are you? And by file I meant the generated file, specifically, the file generated by the exact code in your question.

Comment: yeah the code posted above is not the whole thing. It's two different modules and I think my problem is coming from hidden "\n" in my string maybe when I pass them between functions. My read function opens the text source file, parses through to get times for breaks and lunches and then calls the write function which takes all of those strings and outputs them in csv. stand alone my code above works so I think it's something to do with my string objects I'm sending.

Comment: Ok, so this is a 'non-preproducible'. It's good to write an [MCVE] as you did but you actually have to make sure the 'verifiable' part is true. Also, again, you import the csv module, use it, don't make csv by concatenating strings.

Comment: If you take my code and run the modules you'll run into the same results. I agree though my example in the original question doesn't really explain my problem fully.

Comment: Right but I'm not going to download your code and debug it for you, that's not what the question is about and if I found your bug, it's not going to help anyone else. If you can come up with an example that demonstrates your problem, post that. This one, you can pretty much toss, I think

Comment: I also cannot reproduce your problem when I run that code with Python 3.6. I would also advise you just use the `csv` module.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `csv` module, and a context manager.

```
import csv

monday_break_one = "2:00 PM - 2:15 PM"
monday_break_two = "3:30 PM - 3:45 PM"
day_one_string = "3/27/2017"


mb1s, mb1e = monday_break_one.split(" - ")
mb2s, mb2e = monday_break_two.split(" - ")

with open(r"/Users/rohan/Downloads/outputcsv.txt", "w") as fh:
    writer = csv.writer(fh, delimiter=",")
    writer.writerow(["Subject", "Start", "Date", "Start Time", "End Date", "End Time", "All day Event", "Categories", "Show Time As"])
    writer.writerow(["Break 1"])
    writer.writerow([day_one_string, mb1s, day_one_string, mb1e])
```